# How can I do a Selective Gaussian Blur on OpenCV?

Tags: opencv3.0, gaussianblur

I would like to make a noise reducition filter on OpenCV just like the Gimp's Selective Gaussian Blur:
https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-sel-gauss.html

The filter compares each pixel with its surroundings and only blurs if the difference is lower the a maximum delta.

Comment: I found the implementation here, I think: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl/blob/master/operations/common-gpl3+/gaussian-blur-selective.c

Comment: Basic idea maybe: blur the entire image, get the gradient of the image, and use it as a mask to restore the blurred image back to the original where the gradient is too high. (I just made that up, I don't know what they do in that implementation)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `cv2.bilateralFilter()`: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#bilateralfilter

"`bilateralFilter` can reduce unwanted noise very well while keeping edges fairly sharp. However, it is very slow compared to most filters."